# C# : upload file to a file host

Tags: c#, html, file-upload, upload, web

i have been trying to upload a file to Fileshawk.com from my application.
Here is how i did it :

1- Created a web browser control

2- Loaded the page

3- in the web page it has an input tag of file.

4- i tried to add the file to HTML by using that method which failed.

```
    private void Set_Text_TAG_INPUT(string attribute, string attname, string value)
    {
        // Get a collection of all the tags with name "input";
        HtmlElementCollection htmle = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement current in htmle)
        {
            if (current.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attname))
            {
                current.SetAttribute("value", value);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Set_Text_TAG_INPUT("id","upfile_1342028154587", "FILE.txt");
    }
```

So it didn`t change the value of the Input tag.

Is there any way to add my file to the HTML or page code and about pressing upload i already have a method that invokes the web browser button and click it.

For example , when you click Select file from the input file tag , a window pop up and you select the file , now when you click okay , where is that file stored in the HTML ?

Finally excuse me if i am a newbie in HTML and web knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature in browsers. You cannot programmatically set the value of the value of an input tag of type 'file' since it would introduce a security hole (e.g. a malicious developer could set the value right before handling a submit event and get whatever file they wanted).

Comment: Is there any way i can upload it away from using Web browser or HTML

Comment: I could explain it with MVC, but it looks like you are using WebForms, that is beyond my experience. I would look around MSDN for how to upload a file (probable a WebControl handles it for you?).

Answer (score 0):

Use WebScraper, a C# .NET library to upload file/download file easily, but you need to analyze Fileshawk.com HTML to come up with your own WebScraper syntax, there are totally 22 file host syntax available for sample and already useable.

http://sorainnosia.com/Home/Article/WEBSCRAPER